# Ввод в массив строк с консоли с помощью StringBuffer

Tags: java

Нужно сделать массив строк и консольный ввод с помощью StringBuffer. Со String работает, но когда меняю, выдает ошибки.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    int n = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Введите количество строк: ");

    if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
    } else {
        System.out.print("Введены некорректные данные!");

    }
    String[] text = new String[n];

    keyboard.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        System.out.printf((i + 1) + " ");

        text[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
    }

            System.out.println("String before sort: ");
            for (String element : text ) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
            Arrays.sort(text);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("String after sort: ");
            for (String element : text) {


                System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможны две проблемы:
1- переменную типа `String` можно инициализировать

```
String str = "abc";
```

но переменную типа `StringBuffer` нужно инициализировать по другому

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("abc");
```

соответственно перепишите

```
text[i] = new StringBuffer(keyboard.nextLine());
```

2 - у Java есть встроенное понимание как сортировать объекты `String` (по алфавиту),  т.к. класс `String` уже реализует интерфейс `Comparable`.

```
public final class String
implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {...
```

Но у большинства других классов нет встроенной реализации данного интерфейса. Поэтому применить метод `sort` к массиву `StringBuffer` в лоб не получиться. Нужно указать правило сортировки. Для этого есть перегруженный метод `sort` с компаратором. В нем сортировщику объясняется как сравнить два объекта не реализующих `Comparable`. Создадим новый объект `Comparator` с переопределенным методом `compare` и сравним в нем объекты `StringBuffer` так же, как `String`. Встроенный в `String` метод `compareTo` отлично подойдет.

```
    Arrays.sort(text, new Comparator<StringBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(StringBuffer o1, StringBuffer o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    });
```